# Какое регулярное выражение соответствует графическому смайлу?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пишу регулярное выражение, которое соответствует данной строке:

```
 @id12345 (Сергей Иванов)
```

Не могу придумать, как можно обозначить любой графический смайл? То есть вместо  может стоять любой другой: ✔, ▶ и другие. Регулярное выражение будет использоваться в скрипте на php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать категорию `So`.

Из Свойства знаков Unicode:

> Общая категория (General category)
>   ...
>   Символы (Symbols)
>   **Sm** (symbol, math) — эта категория для знаков, которые используются только в математике. Например, в выражении «sin (π) = 0» только знак равенства можно отнести к категории Sm.
>   **Sc** (symbol, currency) — знаки валюты: цента (¢), доллара ($), лиры (₤), евро (€), иены (¥) и т.д.
>   **Sk** (symbol, modifier) — символы модификации звука и тона. Сюда можно отнести знаки седили, макрона, диереза и т.п.
>   **So** (symbol, other) — всеохватывающая категория символов, которые не являются математическими символами, валютными обозначениями и т.д.

Регулярка для примера

```
/\p{So}/u
```

Пример https://regex101.com/r/CJJbHw/1

Comment: Благодарю! А какое значение в вашем выражении имеют `p` и `u`?

Comment: @Nik, `u` включает режим обработки строки в кодировке UTF-8, про \p{} почитайте тут http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.unicode.php